# Распараллеливание программы с процедурами обратного вызова

Tags: c++, многопоточность, callback

Набросал программу с "действующими лицами" `Producer/Consumer`. Программа выполняется в одном потоке. Исполнение примитивное. `Producer` выполняет определенное действие, периодически "сообщая" `Consumer'у` о состоянии выполнения, а так же опрашивает необходимость прерывания обработки. В конце обработки сообщает об окончании обработки. [Код ниже](https://ideone.com/4hdvpa):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

using TypeCallbackRun = std::function<void (int)>;
using TypeCallbackBreak = std::function<bool (int)>;
using TypeCallbackFinish = std::function<void ()>;

// ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

class Producer {
    TypeCallbackRun CallbackRun;
    TypeCallbackBreak CallbackBreak;
    TypeCallbackFinish CallbackFinish;
  public:
    void Run() {
      std::cout << "Run started (10 times) ...\n";
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (CallbackBreak && CallbackBreak(i)) break;
        if (CallbackRun) CallbackRun(i);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
      }
      if (CallbackFinish) CallbackFinish();
      std::cout << "\nRun finished\n";
    }
    void SetCallbacks(TypeCallbackRun r, TypeCallbackBreak b, TypeCallbackFinish f) {
      CallbackRun = r;
      CallbackBreak = b;
      CallbackFinish = f;
    }
};

// ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

class Consumer {
  public:
    bool Ready = false;
    void ProcCallbackRun(const int i) {
      std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    bool ProcCallbackBreak(const int i) {
      return i > 4;
    }
    void ProcCallbackFinish() {
      Ready = true;
    }
};

// ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

int main() {
  Producer Prod;
  Consumer Cons;
  //
  //  так
  //
  Prod.SetCallbacks(
    std::bind(&Consumer::ProcCallbackRun, &Cons, std::placeholders::_1),
    std::bind(&Consumer::ProcCallbackBreak, &Cons, std::placeholders::_1),
    std::bind(&Consumer::ProcCallbackFinish, &Cons)
  );
  //
  //  ну или так
  //
  //  Prod.SetCallbacks(
  //  [&](int i) {
  //    Cons.ProcCallbackRun(i);
  //  },
  //  [&](int i) {
  //    return Cons.ProcCallbackBreak(i);
  //  },
  //  [&]() {
  //    Cons.ProcCallbackFinish();
  //  });
  Prod.Run();
  return 0;
}
```

**Вопрос**

Как правильно запустить `Producer` в отдельном потоке средствами С++11/14/17 так, чтобы функционал "сообщений" о "состоянии обработки", о "необходимости прерывания", об "окончании обработки" остался работоспособным? Ну или как-то реализовать иначе подобное.

Допустим код ожидания обработки пусть будет примерно таким:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  if (Cons.Ready) break;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
}
```

Т.e. поток с `Producer` должен быть отсоединен сразу посредством [std::thread::detach](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach)

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/84109

Comment: Обычный пример, но функций обратного вызова тут нет. "Общение" через "зашитый" в коде класс-посредник `Buffer`. Такое мне не нужно.

Comment: Не нужно путать конкурентность и параллелизм. В С++ пока что вообще нет библиотеки для работы с процессами, только с потоками. Так что используйте Boost, например.

Comment: А при чем тут процессы? Речь конечно же о потоках.

Comment: Не знаю, вроде же где-то писали про процессы? Или я что-то напутал)

Comment: Наверное напутали)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вроде бы сам решил. Пишите если есть замечания или что-то более лучшее.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

using TypeCallbackRun = std::function<void (int)>;
using TypeCallbackBreak = std::function<bool (int)>;
using TypeCallbackFinish = std::function<void ()>;

std::mutex Mutex;

// ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

class Producer {
    TypeCallbackRun CallbackRun;
    TypeCallbackBreak CallbackBreak;
    TypeCallbackFinish CallbackFinish;
  public:
    void Run() {
      Mutex.lock();
      std::cout << "Run started (10 times): " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
      Mutex.unlock();
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        if (CallbackBreak && CallbackBreak(i)) break;
        if (CallbackRun) CallbackRun(i);
        Mutex.lock();
        std::cout << ".";
        Mutex.unlock();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms);
      }
      if (CallbackFinish) CallbackFinish();
      Mutex.lock();
      std::cout << "\nRun finished: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
      Mutex.unlock();
    }
    void SetCallbacks(TypeCallbackRun r, TypeCallbackBreak b, TypeCallbackFinish f) {
      CallbackRun = r;
      CallbackBreak = b;
      CallbackFinish = f;
    }
};

// ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

class Consumer {
  public:
    std::atomic<int> Counter;
    std::atomic<bool> Ready;
    Consumer () {
      Counter.store(0);
      Ready.store(false);
    }
    void ProcCallbackRun(const int i) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> Lock(Mutex);
      std::cout << "(" << i << ") ";
    }
    bool ProcCallbackBreak([[maybe_unused]] const int i) {
      return Counter.load() > 75;
    }
    void ProcCallbackFinish() {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> Lock(Mutex);
      std::cout << "\nthread finish: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
      Ready = true;
    }
};

// ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

int main() {
  Consumer Cons;
  Producer Prod;    
  Prod.SetCallbacks(
      std::bind(&Consumer::ProcCallbackRun, &Cons, std::placeholders::_1),
      std::bind(&Consumer::ProcCallbackBreak, &Cons, std::placeholders::_1),
      std::bind(&Consumer::ProcCallbackFinish, &Cons)
    );  
  // запуск
  std::cout << "main thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
  std::thread([&]() {
    Prod.Run();
  }).detach();
  while (!Cons.Ready) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms);
    Mutex.lock();
    std::cout << "[" << Cons.Counter.load() << "] ";
    Cons.Counter++;
    Mutex.unlock();
  }
  std::cout << "exit program: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: Поправил код, чтобы компилировался и в C++11, а не только >= С++17. Увеличил задержку в основном потоке, чтобы компилятор не оптимизировал, и не исполнял все в одном потоке. [Пример тут](https://ideone.com/yUmUQ7).

Comment: Только где сдесь само распаралеливание? Всмысле: да, у вас код выполняется в 2 потоках, но не паралельно! Он последовательный (что, собственно, понятно, так как потребитель зависит от поставщика)

Comment: Увы, так соптимизировал компилятор. Я добавил большие задержки - и распараллеливание появилось. Кот в своем сообщении поправил. Ну а убедиться, что распараллеливание действительно есть, можно по выводу программы (по линку).

Comment: что вы несете? Какая еще оптимизация компилятора? У вас банально производитель вызывает потребителя после чего ожидает пока потребитель освободит мьютекс - сдесь нет распаралеливания прямо на уровне кода. Компилятор тут нипричем.

Comment: А касаемо "зависимости от поставшика" - потребитель будет уведомлен посредством обратного вызова `ProcCallbackFinish`. А пока производитель работает - поставщик крутит свой цикл.

Вообще это механизм я планирую для соединения Qt и не-Qt классов, дабы потом это еще завернуть в сигналы-слоты. Ибо производитель у меня будет на голом С++.

Comment: Время захвата мьютекса разное. Что мы спорим? посмотрите вывод программы. А мьютексы только лишь для обеспечения целостного вывода с std::out.

(число) выводит поток производителя, [число] - выводит поток потребителя

Comment: вы меня просто умиляете: мьютекс только для вывода. Вы вкурсе, что мьютекс освобождается только по выходе из методов вашего потребителя? Вы банально путаете многопоточность с распаралеливанием! Да, сдесь есть 2 потока (зачем не понятно, даже однопоточный код будет работать быстрее, чем этот), но никакого распаралеливания у вас и в помине нет.

Comment: Для данного случая (у вас отсутствую какие либо долгие расчеты, да и вообще сам продукт!) нет вообще никакого смысла ни в распаралеливании, ни в потоках. В более сложном случае (при наличии долгих расчетов как на стороне потребителя, так и производителя) за счет асинхрона можно было бы получить выигрыш, но не с вашим кодом!!! То что вы привели будет выполняться даже дольше однопоточного кода!

Comment: что касается: посмотрите вывод... - ну вы не первый, кто (сознательно или нет) переделывает результаты (вывод) так, чтобы он указывал на то, что его гипотеза верна. Вот вам подсказка: введите sleep потока в методы потребителя - посмотрите на ваше "распаралеливание" без розовых очков

Comment: А это что в цикле основного потока - std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms)?

Comment: Специально убрал все мьютексы напрочь, и накидал задержек во все функции. См. вывод - https://wandbox.org/permlink/czXWSbtIFJktEDKn

Comment: Меня не интересует скорость выполнения. Меня интересует возможность периодических уведомлений от Производителя Потребителю. Посмотрите мой вопрос и тот однопоточный пример. И только потом решайте за меня то, что мне нужно. Пожалуйста.

Comment: вы что издеваетесь? Вы сами то вопрос свой видели? У вас первым же словом идет: распаралеливание. И при этом сами же сейчас пишите что ваи не нужно распаралеливание (не интересует скорость выполнения)... Вы бы сами сначала определитесь что вам нужно - я же вам говорю, исходя из того, что написано в вашем же вопросе, что в вашем коде нет никакого распаралеливания - это просто факт!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111048/discussion-between-majestio-and-andrej-levkovitch).